# How to get message and sender sent via Skype with Skype4Java

Tags: java, skype, skype4java

Once I have received a message in Skype, I would like to be able to get the username of the sender as well as the content of the message using Skype4Java. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
message.getContent().getSender().getUsername();
```